# Weird PID less tcp process blocking port 80 keeps apache from starting

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

my machine is running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I installed apache 2 on my system. When I try to start it, I get error

`(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80`

Now this is very common problem regarding apache. most solution are to hit command `netstat -nltp | grep ':80'` then get pid and kill the process. Linux gods are angry in my case I think. When I hit the same command, I get this output.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address  State    PID/Program name

tcp6  0      0      :::80         :::*             LISTEN   -
```

As you can see there is no pid for this process. How can this be? I have restarted machine many times it jst reappears. There is no way for me to kill this process. Please help.

Comment: did you run that command as root?  Only root gets to link sockets to PIDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you run this command as root or via sudo - you don't get to see the PIDs otherwise.

Comment: obviously you gentlemen understand that I am a linux noob :/

Comment: Perfect! with sudo netstat -nltp | grep ':80'. I can see the PID, tnks!